# Libreoffice Vanilla on Mac

Tags: libreoffice

Has LibreOffice Vanilla been removed from the App Store? In Belgium I get a message that this app is not available in your country or region. A few weeks ago it was there.

[LibreOffice Vanilla on App Store](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/libreoffice-vanilla/id921923693?mt=12)

Is there another way of installing LibreOffice on Mac that has *automatic updates*?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I get the same message on the Swiss Mac App Store (your link seems to be correct as it matches the one on libreoffice.org: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-from-microsoft-and-mac-app-stores/). After some research I've found out that the Mac App Store version of LibreOffice is published by Collabora, which has an app called Collabora Office on the Mac App Store. That may be what you are looking for, check whether the app is available in Belgium: https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/collabora-office/id918120011.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `homebrew` project. There are lots of applications available in "casks." You need to be a little familiar with the command line, but if LibreOffice doesn't have auto-update built in, this might be your best bet.

Comment: **LibreOffice** is available from [https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/) in standard **Apple** _DMG Images_ with the standard **Drag & Drop** install method. **Homebrew** is not needed to install **LibreOffice**!

Comment: @user3439894 the OP is looking for a way to keep LibreOffice updates automatically. Using homebrew allows to easily script updates.

Comment: The standard package available from the link in my first comment can be configured in its preferences to check regularly and automatically download updates.

Comment: Homebrew is not **needed** but once you have installed with it, updating is as easy as `brew upgrade --all`.